# Error updating/inserting information

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am recieving this error below:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.

The error occurs only when update or delete is clicked (all textboxes must be complete for update to work). I ended up changing from a SQL database to a Oracle database and I've been having tiny issues here and there. Editing and canceling a row works fine. Below I will include my query:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Insert") //- this is needed to explain that the INSERT command will only work when INSERT is clicked
        {
            gv.DataBind();

            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "", fundCode = "", BSA_CD = "", DP_TYPE = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();
                fundCode = d.Rows[0]["FUND_CD"].ToString();
                BSA_CD = d.Rows[0]["BSA_CD"].ToString();
                DP_TYPE = d.Rows[0]["DP_TYPE"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute("INSERT INTO CIS.CIS_TRANS (ID,TRANS_CD) VALUES(CIS.S_CIS_TRANS.nextval,'')", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }

            gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count - 1;

        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
        {
            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute(string.Format("DELETE CIS.CIS_TRANS WHERE ID = '{0}'", d.Rows[0]["ID"]), "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

If you guys need to me include other parts of my code, please be free to say so. I will include it right away.

Below is my source code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectCISConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ConnectionStrings:ProjectCISConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID ASC" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS WHERE ID = @ID"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO CIS.CIS_TRANS (TRANS_CD,FUND_CD,BSA_CD,DP_TYPE,TRANS_CD_DESC) VALUES (@TRANS_CD,@FUND_CD,@BSA_CD,@DP_TYPE,@TRANS_CD_DESC)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE CIS.CIS_TRANS SET TRANS_CD = @TRANS_CD, FUND_CD = @FUND_CD, BSA_CD = @BSA_CD, DP_TYPE = @DP_TYPE, TRANS_CD_DESC =@TRANS_CD_DESC WHERE ID = @ID">

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but it looks like you have an erroneous S_ in "CIS.S_CIS_TRANS" in your INSERT statement.

Comment: @kakridge that's a SEQUENCE nextval.

Comment: @steve thanks steve ! And yes kakridge its a sequence, It can get confusing with oracle :/

Comment: Where is the update code you talk about in your question? And on which line you receive the exception?

Comment: @Steve - So you need to prepend "S_" to the tablename to get nextval?

Comment: Yeah, looks like your code got cut off.  I thought you were using UPDATE from a general application perspective (insert vs. delete), but it appears you should have another else block.

Comment: No, sequence is an object used to generate unique integers. Just named in that way. See [SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm)

Comment: @Steve, hey steve I include my source code, i edited. Also i noticed when i click delete is crashes as well. It doesn't specifically show me where the code is coming from, I can copy and paste the code error description and details If that would assist you. When I close the web application error, I do see the some arears with a highlighted green mark and if those are whats indicted the error, its the exact codes I posted.

Comment: Got it.  S_CIS_TRANS is the name of the sequence then?  I thought it was a table based sequence.

Comment: Out of my league here, but I don't think you prepare statements with @varname in Oracle.  I thought it was ?.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code following a line like `else if (e.CommandName == "Update")`

Comment: @steve nope I do not. I didnt have one either when i was connected to the SQL database, it worked fine though. I'm just new to converting to a Oracle database and I'm having difficulty understanding the changes.

Comment: You should have an UpdateParameters block or some code that sets the parameters.  We need to see that.

Comment: Try to change the prefix of your parameters name from `@` to `:`

Comment: Which data provider are you using, Microsoft's Oracle Data Provider or Oracle's Data Provider for .NET?

Comment: @Steve you were right. Simple as changing @ to : ! If you could place it as an answer, I will check it off for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle ADO.NET library requires the prefix `:` instead of `@` in every parameter you pass to its engine.

Simply, change the prefix of your parameters from `@` to `:`

Answer (score 0):

Are your ID fields numeric or string.  It may be that Cancel works and DELETE fails because in Cancel, you are using single quotes around your ID value, while in DELETE you are not.